# Is a graph of zero nodes/vertices connected?

Tags: graphs

Suppose there is a graph *G* of zero nodes, there is an even number of nodes. By definition of [connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Connected_graph), the graph *G* is connected when there is a path between every pair of nodes. But there are no pair of nodes since there are zero nodes.

Does this mean *G* is connected because there is a path for every pair of nodes (in this case zero) or would this mean *G* is not connected because there are no paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These issues are discussed in the classical paper [Is the null graph a pointless concept?](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0066433) by Harary and Read. The conclusion is that usually when we think of graphs, we don't think of them as having zero nodes. Definitions which are equivalent for non-empty graphs can differ on the null graph. Whenever we use null graphs we have to be very careful and choose our definitions according to usage.

Given a definition of connectedness, you can check whether the null graph satisfies it. For example, taking your definition (there is a path connecting any two vertices), the null graph is connected since this condition is satisfied vacuously.